# How to used deckgl in "Bing Map"

Tags: bing-maps, deck.gl

We succeeded in displaying nearly 10 million pieces of data on a map using the Google Map API and Deck GL library.
However, I don't like the price and license policy of the Google Map API, so I'm going to change it to Bing Map.
It is difficult to find examples or examples of using Bing Map and Deckgl together on the Internet.
I understand that Deckgl can be used interworking with any base map if it meets a specific condition, but I'm not sure what the specific condition is.

What I want to know is as follows.

1. Can I use it with deckgl?
2. Which map do you prefer if you use Deckgl between OSM and BingMap?
3. Can you handle the map on BingMap? (getCenter, setCenter, etc.)
4. Is there a Map Event? (Clicked Event, Dragged Event, etc.)
5. Is 3D building or setTilt possible like MapBox?

Comment: I'm not familiar with DeckGl, but if you want to have a large number of points on the map and need tilt and rotate, I'd recommend looking at the Azure maps SDK. It should meet the requirements listed above.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

There is no example for this currently, but this could be achieved by adding a canvas to the map as a custom layer. Here is an example: https://bingmapsv8samples.azurewebsites.net/#Canvas%20Layer

Alternatively, consider using Azure Maps. The Azure Maps web SDK wraps MapLibre (open source community fork of Mapbox), Deck.gl was originally writen for Mapbox, so it's not too difficult to access the underlying API in the Azure Maps web SDK and get deck.gl working. I've experimented with this a bit in the past. Here is a quick example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>

    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no" />

    <!-- Add references to the Azure Maps Map control JavaScript and CSS files. -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://atlas.microsoft.com/sdk/javascript/mapcontrol/2/atlas.min.css" type="text/css" />
    <script src="https://atlas.microsoft.com/sdk/javascript/mapcontrol/2/atlas.js"></script>

    <script src="https://unpkg.com/deck.gl@8.4.9/dist.min.js"></script>

    <script type='text/javascript'>
        //https://blog.mapbox.com/coloring-lidar-4522ca5a7186

        var map;

        var arcData, currentStyle;

        function GetMap() {
            //Initialize a map instance.
            map = new atlas.Map('myMap', {
                center: [-85, 35],
                zoom: 5,
                pitch: 30,
                view: 'Auto',
                style:'grayscale_dark',

                //Add your Azure Maps subscription key to the map SDK. Get an Azure Maps key at https://azure.com/maps
                authOptions: {
                    authType: 'subscriptionKey',
                    subscriptionKey: '<Your Azure Maps Key>'
                }
            });


            //Wait until the map resources are ready.
            map.events.add('ready', function () {

                //Load external data.
                fetch('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/visgl/deck.gl-data/master/examples/arc/counties.json')
                    .then(response => response.json())
                    .then(({ features }) => {

                        //Add deck gl layer to map.
                        map.layers.add(new AzureMapsLayer({
                            id: 'arc',
                            data: calculateArcs(features),
                            getSourcePosition: d => d.source,
                            getTargetPosition: d => d.target,
                            getSourceColor: [255, 0, 0],
                            getTargetColor: [0, 255, 0],
                            getWidth: 2,
                            type: deck.ArcLayer
                        }));
                    });
            });
        }

        function calculateArcs(data, selectedCounty) {
            if (!data || !data.length) {
                return null;
            }
            if (!selectedCounty) {
                selectedCounty = data.find(f => f.properties.name === 'New York, NY');
            }
            const { flows, centroid } = selectedCounty.properties;

            const arcs = Object.keys(flows).map(toId => {
                const f = data[toId];
                return {
                    source: centroid,
                    target: f.properties.centroid,
                    value: flows[toId]
                };
            });

            const scale = Math.random();

            arcs.forEach(a => {
                a.gain = Math.sign(a.value);
                a.quantile = scale;
            });

            return arcs;
        }

        class AzureMapsLayer extends atlas.layer.Layer {

            constructor(options) {
                super(options.id);
                this._mbLayer = new deck.MapboxLayer(options);
                this.source = new atlas.source.DataSource();
            }

            /**
            * Internal method for building the mapbox layers.
            * Because this layer only wraps others this is always empty.
            * @internal
            */
            _buildLayers() {
                return [this._mbLayer];
            }

            /**
             * Internal method for getting the ids of the mapbox layers this layer produces.
             * Because this layer wraps others we return their ids.
             * @internal
             */
            _getLayerIds() {
                return [this.id];
            }

            _getSource() {
                return this._mbLayer.source;
            }

            /**
             * @internal
             */
            _getSourceIds() {
                var ids = new Set();
                ids.add(this.source.getId());
                return ids;
            }
        }
    </script>
    <style>
        html, body, #myMap {
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body onload="GetMap()">
    <div id="myMap"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is what the above code generates:

[image]